# clarification on CYPHER dijkstra query how to use WHERE clause in reduce fuction

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to find the shortestpath between two nodes (using dijkstra algorithm) where all the relationships having distance property.
My requirement is I need to filter paths based on the filters provided for nodes or relationships before calling shortestpath.

How to use WHERE caluse in reduce function below for filtering nodes or relationships.

```
  MATCH   p=(a:Place{Name:"US"})-[rels:IS_LOCATED_AT|CARRIES|BELONGS_TO*]-(b:Place{Name:"UK"})
 RETURN p as shortestPath,
 REDUCE(distance=0, r in rels(p) | distance+r.distance) AS totalDistance
ORDER BY totalDistance ASC
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Your Cypher code is not "calling shortestpath" -- it is just getting variable-length paths. Also, please give examples of the kinds of filtering you want to do.

Comment: y requirement is to find SHORTEST DISTANCE between two nodes using Dijkstra algorithm using CYPHER or APOC PROCEDURES with node or relationship FILTER,I have followed iansrobinson.com/2013/06/24/… link . in this link shortest path function is not used.I am new to neo4j.Can you please guide me

Comment: What kind of "filtering" are you trying to do?

Comment: first it should filter the paths using node properties or relationship properties , then among the filtered paths, it should find the shortest paths using dijkstra algorithm using filtered paths' relationship's distance property.

Answer (score 0):

Within a `REDUCE` expression, you can use `CASE` to selectively update the accumulator variable (`distance`, in your example).

As a simple (and silly) example, if you wanted to ignore any `distance` less than 100 miles:

```
REDUCE(distance=0, r in rels(p) | CASE WHEN r.distance >= 100 THEN distance+r.distance ELSE distance END) AS totalDistance
```